# Loop through directory with filenames with numbers in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have to perform a loop through a directory that contains files with the following scheme:

```
P1_1.fq.gz,  P1_2.fq.gz
P2_1.fq.gz,  P2_2.fq.gz
...
P10_1.fq.gz,  P10_2.fq.gz
```

The purpose is take "one line" at a time. For example, in one iteration I must take the first two file and operate on them. Then, take the others two and so on.
How can I loop considering the numbers ? I think It will be something like this:

`for i in {1..10}; do echo P$i_1.fq.gz; done`

I have some problems on how can I take couples and not one file, and with the syntax regarding the letters after the `$i` variable, since I am not so expert with bash scripts.

What can I try next?

Comment: `for i in {1..10}; do file1=P${i}_1.fq.gz; file2=P${i}_2.fq.gz; ...; done`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_1` will be part of your variable this way. The solution is to explicitly tell `bash` what the variable is:

```
for i in {1..10}; do
    echo '------------------'
    echo P${i}_1.fq.gz
    echo P${i}_2.fq.gz
done
```

Comment: This will write them consecutively, not in one line. And this dash line is not required

Answer (score 2):

Loop over the `_1` files and do a replacement to get the `_2` file:

```bash
for f1 in P*_1.gz; do
  f2=${f1/_1/_2}
  echo "$f1 --> $f2"
done
```

The ordering will be P10, P1, P2, ...
If you want them in "numeric" order, you could do:

```bash
printf '%s\n' P*_1.gz \
| sort -V \
| while read -r f1; do
    f2=${f1/_1/_2}
    echo "$f1 --> $f2"
  done
```

Comment: brb submitting pull request for pattern matching and capture in bash globs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=10;i++) printf "P%g_1.fq.gz, P%g_2.fq.gz\n", i}'
```

just ordinary `awk` loop.
One more option in `bash`

```
for (( i=1; i <= 10; i++ ))
do 
echo "P${i}_1.fq.gz, P${i}_2.fq.gz"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name "P*_*.fq.gz" | xargs -n2 -d'\n' |
while read file1 file2; do   
  echo "processing $file1 and $file2"; 
done

processing ./P10_1.fq.gz and ./P10_2.fq.gz
processing ./P11_1.fq.gz and ./P11_2.fq.gz
processing ./P1_1.fq.gz and ./P1_2.fq.gz
processing ./P21_1.fq.gz and ./P21_2.fq.gz
processing ./P22_1.fq.gz and ./P22_2.fq.gz
processing ./P2_1.fq.gz and ./P2_2.fq.gz
processing ./P30_1.fq.gz and ./P30_2.fq.gz
processing ./P3_1.fq.gz and ./P3_2.fq.gz
```